# combining multiple .js files into one in a build process

Tags: javascript, performance

Any tips on combining multiple .js files into 1 (for a build process).

Will yuicompressor do this?

Comment: Follow-up question: any tips on re-writing multiple script tags into one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

YUI Compressor can do this very easily, just send in the file names into [YUI as arguments](http://www.julienlecomte.net/yuicompressor/README) and it will output them as one file.

For example

```
> yuicompressor-2.4.2 file1.js file2.js file3.js -o combined.min.js
```

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know YUI could handle more than one file at once.

Comment: Doesn't work here with YUI compressor 2.4.8, only the last file is taken into account.

Comment: this works : `cat *.js | yuicompressor-2.4.2 --type js -o combined.min.js`  and to choose the proper order 
`cat file1.js file2.js file3.js | yuicompressor-2.4.2 --type js -o combined.min.js`

Answer (score 9):

There's always the old standby (without compression like YUI compressor) `cat file1.js file2.js > newfile.js`

Comment: Doing this as the first command and then the yuicompressor-2.4.2 file1.js file2.js file3.js -o combined.min.js seems to be a winning combination.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
cat file1.js file2.js file3.js | yuicompressor-2.4.2 --type js -o combined.min.js
```

And if order is not important

```
cat *.js | yuicompressor-2.4.2 --type js -o combined.min.js
```

Answer (score 1):

If doesn't work

```
yui-compressor file1.js file2.js file3.js -o combined.min.js
```

try this:

```
for file in file1.js file2.js file3.js
do
  yui-compressor $file >> combined.min.js
done
```